# virtual box guest additions not installing, log file posted

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualbox

I am trying to install the guest additoins for ubuntu, running on virtualbox.

I went to:

/media/vboxaddtions..../

I did a chmod +x on the file that it complained about.

I then ran autorun.sh

The installation failed, and it said to look in the log file, here it is:

```
cat vboxadd-install.log 

Installing VirtualBox 3.0.12 Guest Additions, built Tue Nov 10 11:38:07 CET 2009

Testing the setup of the guest system

Building test kernel module vboxadd_test...

make KBUILD_VERBOSE=1 -C /lib/modules/2.6.35-27-generic/build SUBDIRS=/tmp/selfgz3183/module/test SRCROOT=/tmp/selfgz3183/module/test modules
test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (    \
    echo;                               \
    echo "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";       \
    echo "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
    echo "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";  \
    echo;                               \
    /bin/false)
mkdir -p /tmp/selfgz3183/module/test/.tmp_versions ; rm -f /tmp/selfgz3183/module/test/.tmp_versions/*
make -f scripts/Makefile.build obj=/tmp/selfgz3183/module/test
  gcc -Wp,-MD,/tmp/selfgz3183/module/test/.test.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/include  -I/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.35-27-generic/arch/x86/include -Iinclude  -include include/generated/autoconf.h -Iubuntu/include  -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -O2 -m32 -msoft-float -mregparm=3 -freg-struct-return -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2 -march=i686 -mtune=generic -maccumulate-outgoing-args -Wa,-mtune=generic32 -ffreestanding -fstack-protector -DCONFIG_AS_CFI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SIGNAL_FRAME=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SECTIONS=1 -pipe -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -Wframe-larger-than=1024 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -pg -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fconserve-stack -I/lib/modules/2.6.35-27-generic/build/include -I/tmp/selfgz3183/module/test/ -I/tmp/selfgz3183/module/test/include -I/tmp/selfgz3183/module/test/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -D_X86_ -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_SUP_R0 -DVBGL_VBOXGUEST -DVBGL_HGCM -DVBOX_WITH_HGCM  -DMODULE -D"KBUILD_STR(s)=#s" -D"KBUILD_BASENAME=KBUILD_STR(test)"  -D"KBUILD_MODNAME=KBUILD_STR(vboxadd_test)"  -c -o /tmp/selfgz3183/module/test/.tmp_test.o /tmp/selfgz3183/module/test/test.c
  set -e ; perl /usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.35-27-generic/scripts/recordmcount.pl "i386" "little" "32" "objdump" "objcopy" "gcc" "ld" "nm" "" "" "1" "/tmp/selfgz3183/module/test/test.o";
  ld -m elf_i386   -r -o /tmp/selfgz3183/module/test/vboxadd_test.o /tmp/selfgz3183/module/test/test.o 
(cat /dev/null;   echo kernel//tmp/selfgz3183/module/test/vboxadd_test.ko;) > /tmp/selfgz3183/module/test/modules.order
make -f /usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.35-27-generic/scripts/Makefile.modpost
  scripts/mod/modpost -m -a -i /usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.35-27-generic/Module.symvers -I /tmp/selfgz3183/module/test/Module.symvers  -o /tmp/selfgz3183/module/test/Module.symvers -S -w  -s
  gcc -Wp,-MD,/tmp/selfgz3183/module/test/.vboxadd_test.mod.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/include  -I/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.35-27-generic/arch/x86/include -Iinclude  -include include/generated/autoconf.h -Iubuntu/include  -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -O2 -m32 -msoft-float -mregparm=3 -freg-struct-return -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2 -march=i686 -mtune=generic -maccumulate-outgoing-args -Wa,-mtune=generic32 -ffreestanding -fstack-protector -DCONFIG_AS_CFI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SIGNAL_FRAME=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SECTIONS=1 -pipe -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -Wframe-larger-than=1024 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -pg -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fconserve-stack -I/lib/modules/2.6.35-27-generic/build/include -I/tmp/selfgz3183/module/test/ -I/tmp/selfgz3183/module/test/include -I/tmp/selfgz3183/module/test/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -D_X86_ -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_SUP_R0 -DVBGL_VBOXGUEST -DVBGL_HGCM -DVBOX_WITH_HGCM  -D"KBUILD_STR(s)=#s" -D"KBUILD_BASENAME=KBUILD_STR(vboxadd_test.mod)"  -D"KBUILD_MODNAME=KBUILD_STR(vboxadd_test)"  -DMODULE -c -o /tmp/selfgz3183/module/test/vboxadd_test.mod.o /tmp/selfgz3183/module/test/vboxadd_test.mod.c
  ld -r -m elf_i386 -T /usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.35-27-generic/scripts/module-common.lds --build-id -o /tmp/selfgz3183/module/test/vboxadd_test.ko /tmp/selfgz3183/module/test/vboxadd_test.o /tmp/selfgz3183/module/test/vboxadd_test.mod.o
Inserting the test module module/test/vboxadd_test.ko into the kernel.
Building test kernel module vboxadd_test_drm...

/tmp/selfgz3183/module/test_drm/Makefile.include.header:97: Using BUILD_TYPE='release' from the environment.
make KBUILD_VERBOSE=1 -C /lib/modules/2.6.35-27-generic/build SUBDIRS=/tmp/selfgz3183/module/test_drm SRCROOT=/tmp/selfgz3183/module/test_drm modules
test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (    \
    echo;                               \
    echo "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";       \
    echo "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
    echo "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";  \
    echo;                               \
    /bin/false)
mkdir -p /tmp/selfgz3183/module/test_drm/.tmp_versions ; rm -f /tmp/selfgz3183/module/test_drm/.tmp_versions/*
make -f scripts/Makefile.build obj=/tmp/selfgz3183/module/test_drm
/tmp/selfgz3183/module/test_drm/Makefile.include.header:97: Using BUILD_TYPE='release' from the environment.
  gcc -Wp,-MD,/tmp/selfgz3183/module/test_drm/.test_drm.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/include  -I/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.35-27-generic/arch/x86/include -Iinclude  -include include/generated/autoconf.h -Iubuntu/include  -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -O2 -m32 -msoft-float -mregparm=3 -freg-struct-return -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2 -march=i686 -mtune=generic -maccumulate-outgoing-args -Wa,-mtune=generic32 -ffreestanding -fstack-protector -DCONFIG_AS_CFI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SIGNAL_FRAME=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SECTIONS=1 -pipe -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -Wframe-larger-than=1024 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -pg -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fconserve-stack -I/lib/modules/2.6.35-27-generic/build/include -I/tmp/selfgz3183/module/test_drm/ -I/tmp/selfgz3183/module/test_drm/include -I/tmp/selfgz3183/module/test_drm/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_SUP_R0 -DVBOX -DVBGL_VBOXGUEST -DVBOX_WITH_HGCM -DLOG_TO_BACKDOOR -DRT_WITH_VBOX -DIN_MODULE -DIN_GUEST_R0 -DRT_ARCH_X86  -DMODULE -D"KBUILD_STR(s)=#s" -D"KBUILD_BASENAME=KBUILD_STR(test_drm)"  -D"KBUILD_MODNAME=KBUILD_STR(vboxadd_test_drm)"  -c -o /tmp/selfgz3183/module/test_drm/.tmp_test_drm.o /tmp/selfgz3183/module/test_drm/test_drm.c
  set -e ; perl /usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.35-27-generic/scripts/recordmcount.pl "i386" "little" "32" "objdump" "objcopy" "gcc" "ld" "nm" "" "" "1" "/tmp/selfgz3183/module/test_drm/test_drm.o";
  ld -m elf_i386   -r -o /tmp/selfgz3183/module/test_drm/vboxadd_test_drm.o /tmp/selfgz3183/module/test_drm/test_drm.o 
(cat /dev/null;   echo kernel//tmp/selfgz3183/module/test_drm/vboxadd_test_drm.ko;) > /tmp/selfgz3183/module/test_drm/modules.order
make -f /usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.35-27-generic/scripts/Makefile.modpost
/tmp/selfgz3183/module/test_drm/Makefile.include.header:97: Using BUILD_TYPE='release' from the environment.
  scripts/mod/modpost -m -a -i /usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.35-27-generic/Module.symvers -I /tmp/selfgz3183/module/test_drm/Module.symvers  -o /tmp/selfgz3183/module/test_drm/Module.symvers -S -w  -s
  gcc -Wp,-MD,/tmp/selfgz3183/module/test_drm/.vboxadd_test_drm.mod.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/include  -I/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.35-27-generic/arch/x86/include -Iinclude  -include include/generated/autoconf.h -Iubuntu/include  -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -O2 -m32 -msoft-float -mregparm=3 -freg-struct-return -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2 -march=i686 -mtune=generic -maccumulate-outgoing-args -Wa,-mtune=generic32 -ffreestanding -fstack-protector -DCONFIG_AS_CFI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SIGNAL_FRAME=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SECTIONS=1 -pipe -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -Wframe-larger-than=1024 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -pg -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fconserve-stack -I/lib/modules/2.6.35-27-generic/build/include -I/tmp/selfgz3183/module/test_drm/ -I/tmp/selfgz3183/module/test_drm/include -I/tmp/selfgz3183/module/test_drm/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_SUP_R0 -DVBOX -DVBGL_VBOXGUEST -DVBOX_WITH_HGCM -DLOG_TO_BACKDOOR -DRT_WITH_VBOX -DIN_MODULE -DIN_GUEST_R0 -DRT_ARCH_X86  -D"KBUILD_STR(s)=#s" -D"KBUILD_BASENAME=KBUILD_STR(vboxadd_test_drm.mod)"  -D"KBUILD_MODNAME=KBUILD_STR(vboxadd_test_drm)"  -DMODULE -c -o /tmp/selfgz3183/module/test_drm/vboxadd_test_drm.mod.o /tmp/selfgz3183/module/test_drm/vboxadd_test_drm.mod.c
  ld -r -m elf_i386 -T /usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.35-27-generic/scripts/module-common.lds --build-id -o /tmp/selfgz3183/module/test_drm/vboxadd_test_drm.ko /tmp/selfgz3183/module/test_drm/vboxadd_test_drm.o /tmp/selfgz3183/module/test_drm/vboxadd_test_drm.mod.o

Building the VirtualBox Guest Additions kernel module.

make KBUILD_VERBOSE=1 -C /lib/modules/2.6.35-27-generic/build SUBDIRS=/tmp/vbox.0 SRCROOT=/tmp/vbox.0 modules
test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (    \
    echo;                               \
    echo "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";       \
    echo "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
    echo "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";  \
    echo;                               \
    /bin/false)
mkdir -p /tmp/vbox.0/.tmp_versions ; rm -f /tmp/vbox.0/.tmp_versions/*
make -f scripts/Makefile.build obj=/tmp/vbox.0
  gcc -Wp,-MD,/tmp/vbox.0/.cmc.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/include  -I/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.35-27-generic/arch/x86/include -Iinclude  -include include/generated/autoconf.h -Iubuntu/include  -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -O2 -m32 -msoft-float -mregparm=3 -freg-struct-return -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2 -march=i686 -mtune=generic -maccumulate-outgoing-args -Wa,-mtune=generic32 -ffreestanding -fstack-protector -DCONFIG_AS_CFI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SIGNAL_FRAME=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SECTIONS=1 -pipe -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -Wframe-larger-than=1024 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -pg -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fconserve-stack -I/lib/modules/2.6.35-27-generic/build/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/ -I/tmp/vbox.0/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_SUP_R0 -DVBOX -DVBGL_VBOXGUEST -DVBOX_WITH_HGCM -DLOG_TO_BACKDOOR -DRT_WITH_VBOX -DIN_MODULE -DIN_GUEST_R0 -DRT_ARCH_X86  -DMODULE -D"KBUILD_STR(s)=#s" -D"KBUILD_BASENAME=KBUILD_STR(cmc)"  -D"KBUILD_MODNAME=KBUILD_STR(vboxadd)"  -c -o /tmp/vbox.0/.tmp_cmc.o /tmp/vbox.0/cmc.c
In file included from /tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux/the-linux-kernel.h:38,
                 from /tmp/vbox.0/cmc.c:21:
/tmp/vbox.0/include/iprt/types.h:87: fatal error: linux/autoconf.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [/tmp/vbox.0/cmc.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/tmp/vbox.0] Error 2
make: *** [vboxadd] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the headers for the Linux kernel on your guest system for the guest additions to install properly, because they require kernel modules to work.  To install them, run the following command on a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```